# Orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,2\pi)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I learned that the functions $e_n = \dfrac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ are orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, the set of square integerable functions on a torus. But then I saw that the same functions are also the orthonormal basis of the space $L^2(0,2\pi)$, the set of square integrable functions that are not necessarily periodic.

Why is that the case? Why is it that we can *ignore* the condition for periodicity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very important: $L^2(0, 2\pi)$ is *not* the set of square integrable functions on $(0, 2\pi)$. The reason is that the "inner product" on this set is not an inner product: there are nonzero square-integrable functions $f$ such that

$$\langle f, f \rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)|^2 \, dx = 0$$

(for example the indicator function of a point). $L^2(0, 2\pi)$ is the *quotient* of the vector space of square integrable functions by the subspace of functions with the above property, and as a result its elements are not functions, but equivalence classes of functions. This taking of equivalence classes destroys the information of what value a function takes at the endpoints, and in fact destroys the information of what value a function takes on any particular subset of $(0, 2\pi)$ of measure zero, which is why it doesn't matter whether you impose periodicity or not, or whether you work with $(0, 2\pi)$ or $[0, 2\pi]$.

Similarly, the condition that a bunch of functions (really their equivalence classes) forms an orthonormal basis means that certain sequences converge in the $L^2$ sense, and this is much weaker than, and does not imply, pointwise convergence. So a series of periodic functions can converge in the $L^2$ sense to a function that is not periodic.

Comment: Just to check my understanding, am I right that even if I start with a function $f$ which is not periodic on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, I can find a periodic representation of $f$ which has the same $L^2$ norm by redefining $f$ at both end points so that the resulting function is periodic?

Comment: @nan: yes, you can find a periodic function which maps to the same element of $L^2$, which is a much stronger statement.